# OnFinishInflate inside ListActivity

Tags: android

I have a main class filled with a cursor adapter:

```
public class MainMenu extends ListActivity{ 
... 
private void updateData(){ 
... 
SimpleAdapter notes = new SimpleAdapter(this, array, R.layout.row_task, from, to); setListAdapter(notes); 
} 
}
```

I need to know when this list has finnished to inflate it, so I've discovered this methods:

ListView.onFinishInflate()...

But I have no idea how to override it inside my code.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need your own View that will extend ListView. And than you can override whatever you want.
Note: Method is not specific to the ListView it's inherited from View. But since you'll need functionality of the ListView you'll need to extend ListView.